# UILabel was circular, now has become eliptical

Tags: swift, uilabel

I was using the following code in swift:

```
label.layer.cornerRadius = CGRectGetWidth(label.frame) / 2
label.layer.masksToBounds = true
```

This worked well, but I then made my row height taller, it was 44 and then I made it 66 tall. Now the circular label is elliptical. 
[image]

I notice that when I make `maskToBounds` is false I can see the label's background is more of a rectangle. It's wide and not as tall as the label is even though it's dimensions are set to be square. What am I doing wrong?

[image]

**Updated**
Here are my constraints:
[image]

Within `override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` I am calling a function called Configure cell which takes a UITableViewCell and just updates the text.

```
func configureTextForCell(cell: UITableViewCell, withPlayer player: Player){
    let jerseyLabel = cell.viewWithTag(3000) as! UILabel
        jerseyLabel.text = String(player.jerseyNumber)
    circleLabels(jerseyLabel, hex: "#6470FF")

}
```

`CircleLabels()` is like this:

```
    func circleLabels(label: UILabel, hex: String){
    label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.width/2
    label.layer.masksToBounds = true
}
```

Comment: Did you also make it 66 _wide_?

Comment: Make sure you constrain your label to a 1:1 aspect ratio

Comment: @tktsubota I made the row height 66 and the UIlabel 43x43

Comment: @Sam just added in 1:1 aspect ratio and it's still elipitcal

Comment: Use cornerRadius = label.frame.size.width/2 if you want the top and bottom to be completely curved and cornerRadius = label.frame.size.height/2 if you want the left and right axis to be completely curved. Otherwise make sure the aspect ratio is 1:1 to make it circular and then use either width or height

Comment: @Sam I adjusted my code to `label.layer.cornerRadius = label.frame.size.width/2
        label.layer.masksToBounds = true` and aspect ratio is 1:1 and still the same shape

Comment: Note here that the issue isn't that the cornerRadius is wrong, its that your label isn't square. If your label was square then the cornerRadius code will work to make it circular. So you should be investigating why your label is rectangular and not square. Maybe it has something to do with when this is being called relative to it being laid out. But without more code/pictures we can't really help further

Comment: @Sam Thanks Sam, I'm not very experienced with iOS what would be of help to you here in terms of pictures and code and i'll update the Q

Comment: Please add images of the function where you are setting this. Any code where you might change the frame of the label. How you are laying out the label (constraints in the storyboard)

Comment: @Sam Updated my question with hopefully enough info

Comment: Make sure the cell height is 66 both on the storyboard and in the code (heightForRowAtIndexPath)

Comment: @Sam Thanks Sam, If you put this as an answer i'll mark it correct. I actually went for `self.tableView.rowHeight = 66.0` in viewDidLoad(), is that acceptable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems to be an issue with when the call is made compared to when the cell is laid out. An easy fix is to just make the cell the same size in both the storyboard and in code

```
self.tableView.rowHeight
```

or in the delegate function)